# Mixing overlapping colours in a barchart

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 3 barcharts on one plot, each of which is mapping a different RGB channel (so one red chart, one blue chart, one green chart). Since they're all on the same plot I want the colours to mix with any colours in front or behind them so I can clearly see the overlap zones. For example if there's a red and a green bar overlapping each other, the overlap region should be yellow.

Is this possible?

I've tried setting the alpha of the entire plot to 0.7, which allows me to see the overlaps, but the colours are completely off (red and green make a slightly darker green).

```
hold all
bar(offset, rCount, 1, 'r')
bar(offset, gCount, 1, 'g')
bar(offset, bCount, 1, 'b')
alpha(0.7)
```

Comment: Why would mixing red and green give you yellow?

Comment: That's how it is with RGB light: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/AdditiveColor.svg